# Closing question

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037446/registry-startup-enabling-and-disabling

Someones voted to close this and I can't really see the rational behind someone doing that so why are these votes anonymous and why is no reason given?

Comment: Perhaps they were indicating that a little clarification was warranted in your question. Your last paragraph is a bit hard to parse: "but I cant find out how they do this as in the registry the key is either there or it is not and the value is always the path to the executable so can anyone tell me how to query the status and change the status of the startup items?"

Comment: @BradLarson The close reason is offtopic; stating that this question belongs on SU.  He didn't vote it as being unclear.

Comment: Well the question belongs on stack overflow as its something to be done programmatically.

Comment: You need to stop taking votes personally. There's nothing 'rude', 'anti-social', etc about down votes or voting to close, they relate to the question, not to the person who asked it

Comment: Just FYI, insulting people for downvoting you is likely to attract downvotes, not inhibit them, and will likely remove any possibility of further constructive discussions on the topic.

Comment: Re the down-votes. On Meta sites they don't just mean that the question is unclear or not useful they can (and are) used to show disagreement with the position being proposed. As there is no reputation here there's no penalty to you.

Comment: Well if you think about things people come to ask a question then for random reasons others want to close that question thus depriving the person of an answer and that is anti social and can only be deemed as counter productive to a Q+A site as all that is likely to happen is the person asks elsewhere in a more welcoming environment.

Comment: Please read the description of the downvote button: "This question **does not show any research effort**, is unclear or **not useful**" (emphasis mine). Your question isn't particularily useful as you're worrying about the reason for one single close vote; it lacks research as you could have found out yourself what the close reason is (and you don't seem to know that there is _always_ a close reason given, but it's not publicly visible if the question is still open). Also, the whole "please explain votes and leave comments everywhere"-thing has been discussed to death here.

Comment: My question is useful to me as I wanted an answer, that I got, so without being rude its irrelevant to me if my question was meaningful to you because its my question not yours.

Comment: And re "anti social"/"counter productive": The goal of SO is **not** to be a Q/A site for everybody. It is to create a repository of _high quality_ questions and answers useful to a larger audience, _not just to the person who originally asked it_. This should make it obvious that we don't want people here who just dump their homework or debugging problems without caring for the sites quality standards. And of course, we need to closevote and downvote a huge amount of questions to uphold these goals. If that makes people who ask unwelcome questions feel unwelcome, that's not a bad thing.

Comment: If you're going to respond to "don't take it personally, it isn't personal" with "I can see a scenario where this could be construed as personal, therefore I take it personally", you're unlikely to find a satisfactory answer to your question here. Voting simply isn't anti-social, nor rude

Comment: @Col_Blimp Your last comment shows that you did not get what SO is about. This question is not useful _to a larger audience_, hence it should be downvoted. As you said, you got your answer; so don't call the people who actively answer your confused questions "anti social".

Comment: It's irrelevant to you whether your question is useful to others? Sounds rather anti-social behaviour to me, how ironic

Comment: I know know, through asking here, that the post on so was voted to be closed because the person thought it was better asked on su now that I know this I can now add to my so post that I want this done programmatically to avoid any further confusion so my question here was not only relevant it was purposeful thus the down votes here are petty and hasty and looking at them objectionably and holistically shows that anyone asking simply questions is going to be jumped on and down voted and that really is anti social so anyway Im out of here but thanks to Servy for taking the time to get my answer

Comment: @Col_Blimp Note how all of that productive discussion happened [before you started insulting people for downvoting you](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267207/closing-question#comment69746_267207), and that ever since nothing productive has happened.

Comment: - rating someone is insulting them and I suspect you'll disagree but if the ratings have no meaning then they shouldn't be there at all.  I was - rated immediately after posting the question now you personally will struggle to tell me my question was irrelevant since you took the time to provide the answer. I was under the impression that this place was the place to come to get answers about so but clearly the users here dont like that and thats quite sad really especially given not everyone was born knowing everything.

Comment: You seem to be confused about what it is we do here and on the main site.  The question you ask about is off topic--it is about how startup applications are disabled in Windows.  That's a question for SuperUser.  That's why there are close votes.  Also, your butthurt edit is really useless.  I won't bother getting into an edit war with you over it.  If you want, you can quickly scan the questions asked by many of the people you're arguing with in these comments (both here and on [meta.se]) to see how we deal with getting shot down on Meta.  Spoiler: we don't throw a fit.

Comment: Its not off topic its for so and the reason for my question here was to find out why it was voted to be closed so I could change the question to prevent it being closed. I do know so is for programing so I never considered having to specifically state that the question was about programing mind you the winapi and registry tags should have given the game away!

Comment: Let's look at it a different way. If I was asking your question, I'd probably have a sentence that asks, "How do I use the WINAPI in conjunction with [language] to change registry startup keys?". And then I'd state what I'd tried or researched along with any relevant code samples and a specific summary of the part I was having difficulty with. But probably before I even asked the question I'd have had a play with the [Registry Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Sure I get that but does not adding the winapi tag mean the same and posting on the programing site instead of the general system usage site infer its a programing question? I mean if the winapi tag never ment the question was winapi related then what does the winapi tag stand for? Perhaps those seeking to close questions should take in the meaning of the tags before deciding that the question belongs elsewhere.

Comment: Not really, it's up to the asker to make the question as easy to answer and as unambiguous as possible. Imagine you're selling a question to a busy person you owe a favour to. They're taking time out of their day to help _you_, they shouldn't have to infer _anything_.

Comment: Then surely the whole tagging system is redundant then. Adding winapi seems to me as clear as day that the question is about the winapi if not then the tag wouldn't and shouldn't be there. The rational here seem to be that a question should be posted specifically stating its a programing question even though the site is a programing site and thats odd to say the least.

Comment: @Col_Blimp I've now locked your question to stop your nonsensical edits to include commentary about downvotes.

Answer (score 11):

The question *isn't* closed.  One person voted to close.  It takes 5 votes (or a moderator, or a user with a gold badge in a relevant tag for a duplicate closure, neither of which is the case here) to *actually* close the question.

If/when the question is closed a reason will be given along with the names of the user(s) who voted to close.

Of course having the privilege to view close votes on your own question means that you can simply click the "close" button to see what votes have been cast for what reasons even before the question is closed, although the names of the voters won't be visible to you until the question is actually closed.

Comment: I know its not closed and never said it was the question is about the lack of reason for the vote and the anonymity of the vote.

Comment: @Col_Blimp A reason *is* given, actually, although there is no real reason for you to know any of that information if the question isn't actually closed.

Comment: How do I see the reason?

Comment: @Col_Blimp You can read my answer to find out.

Comment: @Col_Blimp as you don't have 3k rep yet, you can only see it if the question was closed. FYI, the reason given is that it's off topic and belongs to super user (debatable, but I can see how one would get the impression).

Comment: @l4mpi No, he can actually vote to close his own question if he wants, and has the full close vote window, since he has 250 rep.  That's only on his own questions though.

Comment: @Servy good to know, I wasn't aware of this detail of the close voting process.